# How to call onchange event with parameter from select

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dom-events

I have this code. One dropdown `name="street"` is populated, then another dropdown is populated according to the value of the prior dropdown.

Now I have to add an radio button and populate the second dropdown according to option checked and first dropdown.

I planed to add `onchange` event in one radio button, but I don't know how to pass as parameter the value for the first dropdown.

This is not working:

```
onchange="GetNumber(<script>document.getElementById("street").value<script>)"
```

segment

```
   <script>
        function GetNumber(street) 
        {
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
        {
    
        console.log(ar);
        
        number.length = 0;
        
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        number.appendChild(option);
        
        ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
        {    
          let option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = item[2];
          option.text = item[1];
          number.appendChild(option);    
        });
        
        }).getNumbers(street);
```

segment

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="<?= url ?>" >   
        
          <label >Indirizzo</label><br>
          <select name="street" onchange="GetNumber(this.value)" >
          <option value="" ></option>
          <? for(var i = 0; i < streets.length; i++) { ?>      
          <option value="<?= streets[i] ?>" ><?= streets[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
          </select><br><br>
          <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="addressType" value="Domestic"   ****magic needed here****>Domestic</label>
              
           <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="addressType" value="Non-Domestic" checked> Non-Domestic</label><br>
          <label >Civico</label><br>
          <select name="number" id="number" onchange="ShowCondominiums(this.value)" >
          </select><br><br>
          <span id="Condominiums" >Condominiums: </span><br>
          <label >Some Data to Store as Sample</label>>
          <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve both the value of 1st dropdown list and the value of radio button.
- You want to update the values of the 2nd dropdown list by using the retrieved values.

### Modification points:

- When I saw your HTML, I confirmed `<input type="radio" name="addressType" value="Non-Domestic" checked>`. In this modification, I would like to propose to use this value as the default value.
- In this modification, when the 1st dropdown list and the radio button are changed, the values of 2nd dropdown list are updated by `GetNumber()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side: `index.html`

```
<form method="post" id="form">
<label >Indirizzo</label><br>
<select name="street" id="select1" onchange="GetNumber('Non-Domestic')" >
<option value="" ></option>
<? for(var i = 0; i < streets.length; i++) { ?>
<option value="<?= streets[i] ?>" ><?= streets[i] ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select><br><br>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="addressType" value="Domestic" onchange="GetNumber(this.value)">Domestic</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="addressType" value="Non-Domestic" onchange="GetNumber(this.value)" checked> Non-Domestic</label><br>
<label >Civico</label><br>
<select name="number" id="number" onchange="ShowCondominiums(this.value)" >
</select><br><br>
<span id="Condominiums" >Condominiums: </span><br>
<label >Some Data to Store as Sample</label>>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br>
</form>

<script>
function GetNumber(addressType){
  var street = document.getElementById("select1").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar){
    console.log(ar);
    number.length = 0;
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    number.appendChild(option);
    ar.forEach(function(item, index){
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item[2];
      option.text = item[1];
      number.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getNumbers(street, addressType);
}
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Unfortunately, I cannot find your Google Apps Script side. So in this modification, I propose the sample script for testing above HTML&Javascript.

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  html.streets = ["a", "b", "c"];
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(), "sample");
}

function getNumbers(street, addressType) {
  return [["", street, street], ["", addressType, addressType]];
}
```

- When you use this modified script, please run `openDialog` at the script editor. By this, a dialog is opened on Spreadsheet and you can test the modified script. So, please copy and paste the above scripts to the container-bound script of Spreadsheet.
- When you open a dialog, and you change the 1st dropdown list is changed, the selected value of 1st dropdown list and the default value (`Non-Domestic`) of the radio button are sent to `getNumbers(street, addressType)`. By this, the 2nd dropdown list is updated. When you change the radio button, the selected value of 1st dropdown list and the changed value of radio button are sent to `getNumbers(street, addressType)`. By this, the 2nd dropdown list is updated again.

### Note:

- In this modification, I'm not sure about the script of your Google Apps Script side. So please modify your actual script using above modified script.